# Uniform convergence of series with nonnegative terms implies uniform convergence of terms to zero

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, absolute-convergence

If I tell you that $S_n(x) = \sum^n_{k=0} \lvert f_k(x)\rvert $ converges uniformly, does it follow that $\lvert f_k(x)\rvert$ converge uniformly to zero?

Assume that $f_k$ are real-valued functions defined on the reals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S_n$ converges uniformly to some function $S$  iff for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N(\epsilon)\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n,m\geq N(\epsilon)$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$\lvert S_n(x) - S_m(x)| < \epsilon$$
(This follows directly from the triangle inequality).
Setting $n=m+1$, we obtain
$$\lvert S_{m+1}(x) - S_m(x)\rvert = \lvert f_{m+1}(x)\rvert < \epsilon\quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}.$$
This is essentially the same argument as in the proof of the fact that the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ implies $a_n\to 0, n\to \infty.$